# Как настроить задачи для cron?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Есть такой таск: пользователь выбирает задачу и время ее выполнения(каждых 5 минут, каждый день и т.д).- это все я записываю в бд.

Есть файлик cron.php который выполняется каждых 5 минут проверяет в бд есть ли активные задачи.

Как правильно записывать в бд время, что бы php понимал стоит ли выполнить задачу или нет.
Допустим пользователь выбрал каждых 5 минут - что записать в бд?

Подскажите кто с этим работал. Буду благодарен :-)

Comment: Я бы хранил наверное интервал запусков в минутах. Запускающий скрипт где то у себя (в той же таблице или в отдельной) хранит для каждой задачи следующее время запуска, т.е. добавляет к текущему времени хранимое кол-во минут и пишет в таблицу. И запускает все задачи у которых время следующего запуска меньше текущего.

Comment: Два поля, last и interval(в минутах). И запускать если TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,last,NOW())>interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хранить в базе интервал в секундах и дату последнего запуска в unix timestamp. В бд добавляем в запрос:
    where (interval + laststart) < now()
Получаем таким образом все задачи которые необходимо выполнить, и после выполнения записываем текущее time() в поле laststart.

Comment: так же хотел сделать, но думал это не совсем правильно и есть другие решения. Но с вашего ответа понял, что это правильно. спасибо

Comment: Возможно есть и другие решения, но данное представляется мне наиболее удобным с точки зрения использования в коде и нагрузки.

Comment: @user3608884 Но вообще из соображений скорости работы лучше было бы все таки хранить уже рассчитанное время запуска, что бы проверять newstart<now() это лучше поддается оптимизации, может работать по индексу. Я конечно понимаю, что у вас там будет десяток записей и оптимизация бессмыслена. но все таки по феншую так :)

Comment: @Mike мне кажется подобным правильнее начинать заниматься от 10 тысяч записей, но тогда уже встанет вопрос того, стоит ли такое количество задач запускать через 1 файл cron.php. А на начальном этапе - такой вариант будет удобнее тем что пользователь "На лету" сможет поменять интервал запуска.

Comment: @ВикторЖариков Зато при моем подходе пользователь на лету сможет указать когда он хочет следующий запуск, что очень удобно при отладке, что бы час не ждать. А при изменении интервала никто не мешает пересчитать и newstart